# Capture 2nd word from an output in Command Prompt in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to capture the 2nd word( i.e. the date) from the 2nd line from the below output of a command(let it be xyz)

```
Data source CODA enabled.
=== 03/13/19 01:45:00 PM
Instance : 0
GBL_COLLECTOR : Nums 12.02.008
GBL_INTERVAL : 299
```

I am using the below syntax, but getting error.

`For /f “tokens=2” %a in (‘xyz | findstr == ‘) do echo %a`

Can anyone help me find the exact syntax to capture the date in the 2nd line ?

Comment: `For /f "tokens=2" %a in ('xyz ^| findstr "==" ') do echo %a`

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the provided information, I would suggest:

```bat
Set "_=1"&For /F "Skip=1Tokens=2" %A In ('xyz 2^>Nul')Do @If Defined _ Echo(%A&Set "_="
```

---

The example you gave, which was answered by [Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman) in his comment, requires removal of all 'smart quotes' and an escape of the pipe character, **`|`**, with a caret, **`^`**:

```bat
For /F Tokens^=2 %A In ('xyz 2^>Nul^|Find "=="')Do @Echo %A
```

Or alternatively, protecting with doublequotes:

```bat
For /F "Tokens=2" %A In ('"xyz 2>Nul|Find "==""')Do @Echo %A
```